# r.html.find only gets 1 item instead of all

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests-html

i have a script that scrapes items by class with requests html.

```
            reviewtext = r.html.find(
            'strong.reviews__item-title', first=True).text
```

However, while the class scraped is assorted to multiple elements (reviews) on the page, only one item (the first review) gets scraped.

How do i implement a for loop or something similiar correctly so my program scrapes the first 3 or a certain number of product reviews, not just the first?

An example product url i try to scrape: https://www.coolblue.de/produkt/832192/eufy-by-anker-robovac-35c.html#product-reviews

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
reviewtexts = r.html.findAll(strong.reviews__item-title')

for reviewtext in reviewtexts:
    print(reviewtext.text)
```

Comment: sadly nothing gets printed there. seems the for loop doesnt work for it

Comment: Reviews data is dynamic. You need something like selenium

Comment: what does dynamic mean

Comment: Meaning data is not in html Dom. They are controlled by javascript

Comment: but in the source code there is no script tag above the reviews so it isnt controlled by js

Comment: When you click all reviews then you will find a pop page with reviews page numbers. That click is controlled by javascript which is dynamic that's why static html can't grab data